# jQuery bind custom function to appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a web app that will allow a user to define a custom JavaScript function and then add a button to their user interface that well preform that function.

Here is a sample of the code

```
var customCommands = {
  command1: {
    text: 'Hello Console',
    cFunctionRun: function() {
      console.log('hello Console!');
    }
  },
  command2: {
    text: 'Hello World',
    cFunctionRun: function() {
      alert('hello World!');
    }
  }
}
```

Then I wrote a small function that loops though and builds the buttons and adds them to the user interface. The problem is when I append the elements to the user interface than click on the buttons nothing works...

Here is one of the methods I tried

```
for (var cmd in customCommands) {
    command = customCommands[cmd];
    button = $('<button/>').html(command.text).on('click', 
      function(){ 
        console.log(command.text); 
        command.cFunctionRun(); 
      }
    );
}
buttonContainer.append(button);
```

Now my loop builds everything just fine and even the `.on('click')` works, but it always displays the text of the lasted added command?

here is http://jsfiddle.net/nbnEg/ to show what happens.

Comment: Could you add more context? What you're showing already works http://jsfiddle.net/nbnEg/

Comment: the second code is in a look... Ill update it now to include the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you actually click, the command variable points to last command (as the whole loop has already run). You should maintain data state per button which tells it which command to invoke. You should do this.

```
for(var i in customCommands) {
  if(customCommands.hasOwnProperty(i)){ //this is a pretty important check
    var command = customCommands[i];
    button = $('<button/>').html(command.text).data("command_name", command).on('click', function(){ 
      console.log($(this).data("command_name").text); 
      $(this).data("command_name").cFunctionRun(); 
    });

    $("body").append(button);
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmLT2/)

Answer (score 1):

all you need is passing the parameter with function, you should try [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data)

Comment: Well this work if the function is alot more complex then just display text. Users are going to use it to help the auto calculated and run custom reports?

Answer (score 0):

It's a (missing) closure problem. The event handler will keep a reference to the value of command on the last iteration of the loop. To solve it you can create a new scope, using an immediately invoked function:

```
for(var cmd in customCommands) {
    (function(command){
        button = $('<button/>').html(command.text).on('click', 
          function(){ 
            console.log(command.text); 
            command.cFunctionRun(); 
          }
        );
        buttonContainer.append(button);
    }(customCommands[cmd]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `button`s should be **unique** (no reason for creating duplicates), I'm setting the button `id` to the `name` of the customCommands (command1 and command2 in this example). This example could easily be adapted to use any of the relative attributes (data-*, name, etc...).

Create a `click` event listener on `document` for whenever one of your `button`s are pressed. Then call the function associated with the given `id`.

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    customCommands[this.id].cFunctionRun();
});

for(var command in customCommands){
    var button = $('<button id="' + command +'"/>').html(customCommands[command].text);
    $("body").append(button);
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/EA5MR/)**

Comment: Thank you, I thought of this as well but I didn't like the idea of having to use an ID tag. Thank you though.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh - Any attribute would work just as well, but the big difference here is the fact that you have a `delegate` event by attaching the event to `document`. This is the way you should go if you're adding dynamic content to the page.