# How to tell if a function is blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a web app (and honestly I dont know what I would do without stackoverflow), but here is what I am doing.

My users can define custom functions, Well right off the bat someone pointed out to me there should be a way to warn the user that the function is blank.

for example a user may write his function to look like this

```
cFunctionRun: function () {}
```

Sadly I have no control over how a function is created which means this very well could happen.

So now I have to find a way to tell the user that this function wont do anything, because well there is nothing it can do. If this is impossible that is fine, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask.

For more information on the cFunctionRun part check out this stackOverflow question [jQuery bind custom function to appended element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738154/jquery-bind-custom-function-to-appended-element/14738582)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Sadly I have no control over how a function is created"

Do you mean that you can't check the function when it is created?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in all cases, so I'm not going to post as an answer, but at least in Chrome you can do `functionName.toString()` and then process it from there... gives you a starting point at least

Comment: @Rasmus yes, I have no way to check the function when it is being created. It is kinda annoying.

Comment: @BLSully can you help me understand this more. I don't quite understand that.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh: See Cerbrus' answer. That's the expanded version of what I was saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

Assuming you have something like this:

```
var functions = {
    aFunctionRun: function () {return false;}
    bFunctionRun: function ('foobar') {}
    cFunctionRun: function () {}
}
```

Try this code:

```
function isEmpty(function){
    // Get the string from the function;
    var funcString = function.toString();
    // Cut off the part before the actual content of the function
    funcString = funcString.substr(funcString .indexOf(')'))
        .replace(/function|[(){};]/g,'') // remove the function keyword, and the following characters: (){};
        .trim();                         // remove any leading / trailing whitespaces and 
    return funcString === '';            //check if it's an empty string.
}

isEmpty(functions.aFunctionRun); // returns false
isEmpty(functions.bFunctionRun); // returns true
isEmpty(functions.cFunctionRun); // returns true
```

Comment: what about: function(){ /* test */ }

Comment: @Corneliu: If we're going to have to consider comments, be it single-line, nested, or improperly nested (`/* foo /* bar */ foobar */`), that's pretty much going to be a pain in the ass to parse.

Comment: There's also the `function myFunction () {}` and `function (foo,bar) {}`

Comment: @KevinB: this should do it.

Comment: @vsync: what if there's a space between the brackets?

Comment: @Cerbrus Seems to be doing the job perfectly!

Comment: ok, better: `var x = function(){    };` then do 
`x.toString().replace('}','').trim() === 'function (){'` skips all the unnecessary regex

Comment: @vsync: what about cases like `function()`, `function ( )`, `function (not_used_parameter)`, etc? the regex is quite necessary.

Comment: yes you are right. I'll look harder.

Comment: `var x = function (a) {    };` 
`var s = x.toString().replace('}','').trim();` 
`s.indexOf('{') == s.length-1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toString` on the function and remove the whitespace to see if the function is empty.

```
var isEmpty = cFunctionRun.toString().replace(/\s+/g, '') === 'function(){}';
```

Comment: If I try this in IE7: `var a = function(){};`, followed by: `a.toString()`, it returns `"function(){}"`. No problems there. Same for the regex replace.